# Unable to connect to oracle database 11g R2

Tags: oracle11gr2

Till yesterday everything was working perfectly. There was an automatic windows update and after that I have been getting the error while trying to connect to my database from sqlplus:

```
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

I tried using the EM and there i got this:

```
Database Instance
Host        
abc-PC
Port        
1521
SID     
mydb
Oracle Home     
D:\app\abc\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
Listener
Status      
Down
Host        
abc-PC
Port        
1521
Name        
LISTENER
Oracle Home     
D:\app\abc\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
Location        
D:\app\kaos\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
Details     Although a Listener with name "LISTENER", is running on this host at port: "1521", it was not started using this target's "LISTENER.ORA" file. 
CORRECTIVE ACTION: To monitor this "EM Listener Target" with its present configuration, you must stop the currently running listener process, and start it again using the Listener Parameter file: D:\app\kaos\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN/listener.ora . 
Alternatively, you can update this target's "LISTENER.ORA Location" parameter with the location of the currently running Listener, which was started using: D:\app\abc\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
```

What am I supposed to do to fix this?

Comment: it looks like your database is down.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe update somehow remove `ORACLE_SID` environment variable. Check `My Computer -> Properties -> Environment variables -> ORACLE_SID`